# how too define a string using pointers in C language?

Tags: c, string, pointers, input, scanf

what do you think has happened 
how does the pointer named name get the size of the string?
please clarify step by step

```
main()
{ char *name;
 scanf("%s",name);
printf("hi %s ! \n",name);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, the size of strings is not stored anywhere (unless you do it).

"strings", actually arrays of characters, end with the value 0 (`'\0'`).

It's a convention.

Library functions like `printf` expect the array of characters to have a byte 0 at some point, to mark the end of the string.

The code

```
char *name = "hekal";
```

will translate in memory into

```
-------------
|h|e|k|a|l|0|
-------------
```

the last `0` is the byte 0 (integer 0), not the ASCII character `0`.

Of course you need to make some space for `name`!

Try

```
 char name [100];
```

instead of `char *name;`;

Comment: This means the above code cant work?
and we cant use pointers to input string?

Comment: This means that since you use `scanf` to read the string, it will end with a `0`, then you use `printf`, using a `"format"` (thus ending with 0), that expects `%s` a string ending with 0. That's the case since `name` ends with a 0 => ok.

Comment: but when I tried to run code it crashes after entering any name for example I entered
-----
name
-----
then it shows msg .exe stopped working

Comment: Read my edit for `name`.